# Forcing PFA with ccc forcing

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

Is it consistent (from suitable large cardinals) that there is a ccc poset which forces PFA?

This seems quite implausible to me. If we could force PFA via ccc forcing, the ground model would have to be quite close to a model of PFA (having the correct continuum, no squares, SCH holding etc.). However, the ground model cannot be a model of full PFA (or even BPFA), since it follows from a result of Caicedo and Veličković that *any* ccc forcing over such models destroys BPFA.

The reference for the Caicedo-Veličković result is

> Andrés Eduardo Caicedo and Boban Veličković, *The bounded proper forcing axiom and well orderings of the reals*, Math. Res. Lett. **13** (2006), no. 3, 393--408. ([link](http://intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/mrl/2006/0013/0003/MRL-2006-0013-0003-a005.pdf))

They show that if $V$ and an inner model $M$ agree on $\omega_2$ and both satisfy BPFA then they have the same subsets of $\omega_1$. The conclusion above follows since any ccc forcing adds a subset of $\omega_1$.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the Caicedo-Velickovic result?

Comment: @PaulMcKenney I've added a reference.

Comment: The only "nontrivial" that a ccc forcing can really do and not destroy PFA is to shoot branches through Suslin trees. (Or so I think, anyway.) Which is of course consistent with your observation from the paper of Andres and Boban. But it seems really weird if that might happen. E.g. if you add a Cohen real to a model of PFA and somehow revive PFA by shooting branches through the Suslin trees you've added and restoring all sort of cardinal invariants to their rightful size.

Comment: (And yes, that does seem a bit implausible!)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Forcing with a Suslin tree forces $\mathfrak{t}= \omega_1$. This is Lemma 2 in Farah, 'OCA and towers in P(N)/fin', but there it is mentioned that Booth would have known of this result.

Comment: @tci: But what happens when you force with a long iteration of Suslin tree *and* other ccc forcings?

Comment: @Asaf, didn't Miha already address this strategy in his question?

Comment: @Paul: How? Miha pointed out that you must add some subsets of $\omega_1$ (either reals or Suslin-branches); tci pointed out that forcing with just one Suslin tree cannot force PFA back (and the same can be said about a lot of ccc forcings); I suggested that perhaps doing something like that, but then finding some sufficiently long (read: $\omega_2$-length) iteration of ccc forcings that fix all the problems we caused *might* work, but that sounds implausible indeed. So I think that Miha's question and my suggested strategy are quite distinct. No?

Comment: @AsafKaragila So you would start with a model of PFA, add a Suslin tree (not via ccc forcing, so maybe using Jech's poset) to kill PFA and then try to resurrect it by ccc forcing? Could it be that if you just force MA and $\mathfrak{c}=\omega_2$ over that you recover PFA?

Comment: @Miha: If anything works, my guess would be that *that* approach would work. Still seems a bit unlikely. I talked with Assaf Rinot and he pointed that for him, and I guess this should be a key point for the rest of the discussion, the difference between MA and PFA is that PFA kills club guessing. And ccc forcings cannot kill club guessing. So when you break PFA you need to ensure that you haven't added any club guessing principles. What exactly that means for the approach we bring up here? I'm not sure, I'm not particularly knowledgeable about club guessing.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood; I thought you were suggesting adding a Suslin tree by Cohen forcing or something like that.

Comment: @Paul: That was an off hand suggestion of a way to kill PFA in a "relatively" tame way. Whether or not you can restore PFA after adding a Cohen real without collapsing cardinals, I don't know. I wouldn't be surprised in most "naive" approaches would not work as they might add some robust enough statements. But what happens if you add some real, change some cardinal characteristics, and then "fix it by forcing MA", as Miha suggested? Again, I don't know. I'd expect the answer to still be negative; and if that doesn't work, I wouldn't expect anything to work (so the answer would be negative).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think a negative answer can be derived from the following observations.

One. A nontrivial c.c.c. forcing adds a subset of $\omega_{1}$ (consider the least cardinal $\kappa$ for which it adds a subset of $\kappa$, and the tree of possible initial segments for this subset; the splitnodes in the tree give rise to a name for a new subset of $\omega_{1}$).

Two. A c.c.c. partial order $P$ has the property that for any ordinal $\delta$, if in a $P$-extension one has a continuous $\subseteq$-increasing 
chain $\bar{N} = \langle N_{\alpha} : \alpha < \omega_{1} \rangle$ of countable subsets of $\delta$ with union $\delta$, then for some club $C \subseteq \omega_{1}$ in the ground model, $\langle N_{\alpha} : \alpha \in C \rangle$ exists already in the ground model. Now if we look at Justin Moore's MRP coding for subsets of $\omega_{1}$ as in Section 4 of this paper (http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0501526v1.pdf) we see that every subset of $\omega_{1}$ coded in a $P$-extension by such a sequence $\bar{N}$ would be coded already by restriction of $\bar{N}$ in the ground model.

Comment: So we can even say more, that MRP cannot be forced with a ccc forcing (unless it held true in the ground model maybe?).

Comment: Yes, I think that's right.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, this was very helpful.